# Getting error while npm start

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I am getting error when I ran command `npm start`.  I have node version `v6.9.1` and npm version `3.10.8`

Below are the path variables for my system:

- User variables PATH: `C:\Users\Abdul Ovais\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- System variables Path: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

Below are the error lines:

```
Abdul Ovais@DESKTOP-31UBAGF /xampp/htdocs/ees-angular-client
$ npm start

> EES@1.0.0 start D:\xampp\htdocs\ees-angular-client
> npm run server:dev


> EES@1.0.0 server:dev D:\xampp\htdocs\ees-angular-client
> webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/

Error: Cannot find module './system/supports-colors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\ees-angular-client\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\node_modules\colors\lib\colors.js:39:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\ees-angular-client\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\node_modules\colors\safe.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\ees-angular-client\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\instance.ts:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server:dev"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! EES@1.0.0 server:dev: `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the EES@1.0.0 server:dev script 'webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the EES package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs EES
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls EES
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\ees-angular-client\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! EES@1.0.0 start: `npm run server:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the EES@1.0.0 start script 'npm run server:dev'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the EES package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run server:dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs EES
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls EES
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\ees-angular-client\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to load some module : './system/supports-colors' and the compiler can't find it

Comment: yes I knew but how I can fix this?

Comment: Well you have to search your project for this line in your code and make sure that this module you are trying to load exists or remove it if it's not needed.

Comment: post your code pls i have same issue solve by another way

Comment: I have the same issue, it works on centos but on windows (both booth2docker and docker for windows) it doesn't work!!!